# for loop does not terminate

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

const int kNumInts = 10;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    vector<int> one(kNumInts);

    cout << one.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); ++i)
    {
        one.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << one.size() << endl;

    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, the for loop does not terminate after 10 iterations. It just never stops. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It'll stop...eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep pushing elements in the vector one and thus, when the for loop condition is tested, the vector's size has increased by 1; and thus it never quits, to fix this change the for loop to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kNumInts ; ++i)
```

Comment: Apparently, he also needs to assign as `one[i] = i`, not `one.push_back(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Index i never reaches one.size()'s value because at the same time that you add elements to the vector, its size increases by 1 every time. Look for another way to limit the number of elements you want to insert into the vector